# How do I fix the error where I cannot make a static reference to a non-static input field?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am learning java. I wrote the following code but I am getting this error "cant make a static reference to a non static input field" in Arrayfunction(), when I try to take input. Why is this so and How can I fix it?

```
import java.util.*;
public class MultidimArrays {

Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String args[])
{       
    int array[][]= new int[2][3];

    System.out.println("Passing array to a function");

    Arrayfunction(array);
}

public static void Arrayfunction(int array[][])
{
    System.out.println("Inside Array function");

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            array[i][j]=input.nextInt();// error
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scanner is not defined as static therefore is in the wrong scope

Either create the Scanner instance inside  `Arrayfunction` or create your scanner with

```
private static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is: As you have not created the object the non-static variable `input` does not exist, so you can not use it.
To fix it you can make `input` as `static`

```
static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

either make your Scanner static and use it inside the static methods or create an instance of the class an access scanner from your static method.

```
static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
public static void Arrayfunction(int array[][])
{          
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            array[i][j]=input.nextInt();// error
 }
```

**OR**

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
public static void Arrayfunction(int array[][])
{
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            array[i][j]=new MultidimArrays().input.nextInt();// error
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `non static` reference is tied to the `instances` of the `class`. While all `static` code is tied to the `class` itself.

You must add the `static keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

`input` in your class is an *instance variable* (since it's not defined as `static`), which means that each instance of `MultidimArrays` has one of it's own. `static` fields or methods (often referred to as "class variables/methods" are shared between all instances of a class.

Since `Arrayfunction` is `static`, it cannot refer to instance members of its class - there is no way for it to know *which* `MultidimArray` to use. You can either solve this by making `input` itself static, or by removing the `static` qualifier from `ArrayFunction` and create an instance of your class:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{       
    int array[][] arr = new int[2][3]; //typo here, variable needs a name :)

    System.out.println("Passing array to a function");
    MultidimArray ma = new MultidimArray();
    ma.Arrayfunction(arr);
}
```